Using Proxy Pass for multi-tenant based software in ingress-nginx (installed by helm)
wildcard-ingress.yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
 name: tenant-specific-ingress
 namespace: <<mynamespace>>
 annotations:
   nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
   nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
   set $tenant_name "";
   if ($host ~* ^(?<tenant>[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)\.mydomain\.com$) {
      set $tenant_name $tenant;
   }
   proxy_set_header X-Tenant-Name $tenant_name;
   nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-snippet: |
   set $backend_service "";
   if ($http_x_backend ~* "staff") {
      set $backend_service "staff-service.<<mynamespace>>.svc.cluster.local";
   }
   if ($http_x_backend ~* "class") {
      set $backend_service "class-service.<<mynamespace>>.svc.cluster.local";
   }
   proxy_pass http://$backend_service;
spec:
 ingressClassName: nginx
 rules:
  - host: "*.mydomain.com"
  http:
    paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: ImplementationSpecific
        backend:
          service:
            name: default-placeholder-service
            port:
              number: 80

I want to dynamically route the traffic to specific service based on the custom header passed in the request.
I've the applied the allow-snippet-annotations: "true" in the ingress controller as well and also tried doing this with two options:
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: 

and
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-snippet

and all together in the
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-snippet

and one time in this:
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-snippet

when I apply k apply -f wildcard-ingress.yaml
I get
Error from server (BadRequest): error when applying patch:
{"metadata":{"annotations":{"kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration":"{\"apiVersion\":\"networking.k8s.io/v1\",\"kind\":\"Ingress\",\"metadata\":{\"annotations\":{\"nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet\":\"set $tenant_name \\\"\\\";\\nif ($host ~* ^(?\\u003ctenant\\u003e[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)\\\\.mydomain\\\\.com$) {\\n    set $tenant_name $tenant;\\n}\\nproxy_set_header X-Tenant-Name $tenant_name;\\n\",\"nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-snippet\":\"set $backend_service \\\"\\\";\\nif ($http_x_backend ~* \\\"staff\\\") {\\n    set $backend_service \\\"staff-service.mynamespace.svc.cluster.local\\\";\\n}\\nif ($http_x_backend ~* \\\"class\\\") {\\n    set $backend_service \\\"class-service.mynamespace.svc.cluster.local\\\";\\n}\\nproxy_pass http://$backend_service;\\n\",\"nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex\":\"true\"},\"name\":\"tenant-specific-ingress\",\"namespace\":\"mynamespace\"},\"spec\":{\"ingressClassName\":\"nginx\",\"rules\":[{\"host\":\"*.mydomain.com\",\"http\":{\"paths\":[{\"backend\":{\"service\":{\"name\":\"default-placeholder-service\",\"port\":{\"number\":80}}},\"path\":\"/\",\"pathType\":\"ImplementationSpecific\"}]}}]}}\n","nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet":"set $tenant_name \"\";\nif ($host ~* ^(?\u003ctenant\u003e[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)\\.mydomain\\.com$) {\n    set $tenant_name $tenant;\n}\nproxy_set_header X-Tenant-Name $tenant_name;\n","nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-snippet":"set $backend_service \"\";\nif ($http_x_backend ~* \"staff\") {\n    set $backend_service \"staff-service.mynamespace.svc.cluster.local\";\n}\nif ($http_x_backend ~* \"class\") {\n    set $backend_service \"class-service.mynamespace.svc.cluster.local\";\n}\nproxy_pass http://$backend_service;\n"}},"spec":{"ingressClassName":"nginx","rules":[{"host":"*.mydomain.com","http":{"paths":[{"backend":{"service":{"name":"default-placeholder-service","port":{"number":80}}},"path":"/","pathType":"ImplementationSpecific"}]}}]}}
to:
Resource: "networking.k8s.io/v1, Resource=ingresses", GroupVersionKind: "networking.k8s.io/v1, Kind=Ingress"
Name: "tenant-specific-ingress", Namespace: "mynamespace"
for: "wildcard-ingress.yaml": error when patching "wildcard-ingress.yaml": admission webhook "validate.nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io" denied the request: 
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Error: exit status 1
2024/12/30 19:05:14 [emerg] 164#164: "proxy_pass" directive is not allowed here in /tmp/nginx/nginx-cfg4213799032:289
nginx: [emerg] "proxy_pass" directive is not allowed here in /tmp/nginx/nginx-cfg4213799032:289
nginx: configuration file /tmp/nginx/nginx-cfg4213799032 test failed

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------


Since this post is not about programming, it is off-topic for Stack Overflow. It may be on-topic on [sf] or DevOps.

According to this link porxy_pass is not allowed in server block(Context allowed: location, if in location, limit_except). So you must add it to configuration-snippet and you must make sure about nginx configuration validation.
